# Python: Dynamically define a validation function with the same signature as a target function?

Tags: python

I have a Python function that takes a relatively large number of arguments. The function is part of a public interface and I need to perform argument validation/normalization on its arguments. I can think of three ways to do this:

```
# METHOD 1: front-loading the function
def func(a1, a2, a3=1, a4=2...):
  # validation code here ...
  # func code here ...

def func_validator(a1, a2, a3=1, a4=2...):
  # validation code here ...

# METHOD 2: passing args to a different function
def func(a1, a2, a3=1, a4=2...):
  func_validator(a1, a2, a3=1, a4=2...)
  # func code here ...

# METHOD 3: decorator
@validator(func_validator)
def func(a1, a2, a3=1, a4=2...):
  # func code here ...

# validator decorator definition ...
```

All three of these methods have problems:

- Method 1: while simple, this makes my code less readable. For a function with many arguments the validation can be quite long. I don't need to see this when I'm trying to understand what the function does.
- Method 2: solves the problem with Method 1 by getting the actual validation code out of the way, but requires writing out the arguments 2x more times.
- Method 3: simply better than Method 2, but I still need to write the function signature twice.

I am aware that I could also use `*args` and `**kwargs`, but this introduces additional in overhead in how I access the arguments in the main function body.

My ideal implementation would allow me to write an external validation function with its argument signature tied to the target function, and apply it with a decorator. Something like this:

```
def func_validator(????):  # how can I tie the argspec to `func`?
  # validation code here ...
  # can access arguments just as if it were inside `func`

@validator(func_validator)
def func(a1, a2, a3=1, ap=2...):
  # func code here...
```

Let me preemptively state that I know such a thing could be abused, but I don't think the use case I've outlined is at all obfuscating. The idea is just to move long validation code out of the main function body and into an adjacent function, without needing to (a) replicate the signature (b) use a generic signature that makes accessing the arguments more verbose.

Is it possible?

Comment: `func_validator` can use `*args` and `**kwargs` and pass them through to `func` (which doesn't need to use `*args` or `**kwargs`).  However, you _need_ to specify the variable names twice anyway since you presumably need to validate them ...  Perhaps if you gave a simple example where the validation is done in `func` we could see what validation is being done and propose some alternatives...

Comment: Also, what version of python are you using?  For newer versions, if you're just validating types, you can probably use function annotations in the validation function.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for your response. As I noted above, I am aware I can use `*args` / `**kwargs` in just the validator. I know that I will need to use the real variable names in the validator itself, so in that sense you are correct that I have to specify them twice anyway. Still, writing the signature over again is one more time I have to write them-- and the validator code won't necessarily deal with every argument. As for Python version, I'm not sure exactly what I need to support but it needs to be at least some version of 2 and 3, and preferably not just the latest.

Comment: @mgilson Also, regarding your request for an example-- I am looking to solve the general problem of extracting long argument validation (and possibly normalization) code from a function. My example is purposefully generic.